# count Number of Swapping element in Quick sort

Tags: javascript

I wrote a program for sorting arrays with quick-sort and I want to get the number of swiping elements in this sort. Sorting the array alphabetically works very well, but it gives me 0 for the number of swipes. This is my code:

```
var items = ["bcd", "abc", "dft", "def", "jhg"];
function swap(items, leftIndex, rightIndex) {
  var temp = items[leftIndex];
  items[leftIndex] = items[rightIndex];
  items[rightIndex] = temp;
}
function partition(items, left, right, count) {
  var pivot = items[Math.floor((right + left) / 2)], //sets the middle element as the pivot
    i = left, //the left pointer
    j = right; // the right pointer
  while (i <= j) {
    while (items[i] < pivot) {
      i++;
    }
    while (items[j] > pivot) {
      j--;
    }
    if (i <= j) {
      console.log("in");
      count++;
      swap(items, i, j); //swaps two elements
      i++;
      j--;
    }
  }
  return { i, count };
}

function quickSort(items, left, right, count) {
  var index;
  count += count;
  // console.log(items);
  if (items.length > 1) {
    index = partition(items, left, right, count); //returns the index from partition
    var newcount = index.count;
    console.log(newcount);
    if (left < index.i - 1) {
      quickSort(items, left, index.i - 1, newcount);
    }
    if (index.i < right) {
      quickSort(items, index.i, right, newcount);
    }
    // return newcount;
  }
  return { items, count };
}
var sortedArray = quickSort(items, 0, items.length - 1, 0);
console.log("final : " + sortedArray.items);// it gives me the sorted array 
console.log("final : " + sortedArray.count); // it gives me 0
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var items = ["bcd", "abc", "dft", "def", "jhg"];
function swap(items, leftIndex, rightIndex) {
  var temp = items[leftIndex];
  items[leftIndex] = items[rightIndex];
  items[rightIndex] = temp;
}
function partition(items, left, right, count) {
  var pivot = items[Math.floor((right + left) / 2)], //middle element
    i = left, //left pointer
    j = right; //right pointer
  while (i <= j) {
    while (items[i] < pivot) {
      i++;
      count++;
    }
    while (items[j] > pivot) {
      j--;
      count++;
    }
    if (i <= j) {
      swap(items, i, j); //sawpping two elements
      i++;
      j--;
    }
  }
  // return the index of the pivot and the number of swaps
  return { index: i, count: count };
}

function quickSort(items, left, right, count) {
  var index;
  count += count;
  console.log("in")
  if (items.length > 1) {
    index = partition(items, left, right, count).index; //index returned from partition
    count = partition(items, left, right, count).count;
    if (left < index - 1) {
      //more elements on the left side of the pivot
      quickSort(items, left, index - 1, count);
    }
    if (index < right) {
      //more elements on the right side of the pivot
      quickSort(items, index, right, count);
    }
  }
  return { items: items, count: count };
}
var sortedArray = quickSort(items, 0, items.length - 1, 0);
console.log("final : " + sortedArray.items); // it gives me the sorted array
console.log("final : " + sortedArray.count); // it gives 4
```

Comment: What did you change, and why? Please [edit] your answer to include an explanation, not just code.